# Resample data to add missing hour values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Im working with a df that looks like this :

```
                        trans_id    amount  month   day     hour
2018-08-18 12:59:59+00:00   1         46    8       18       12
2018-08-26 01:56:55+00:00   2         20    8       26       1
```

I intend to get the average 'amount' at each hour.I use the following code to do that:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['month', 'day', 'day_name', 'hour'], as_index = False)['amount'].sum()
```

That gives me the total amount each month day day_name hour combination which is ok. But when I count the total hours for each day they all are not 24 as expected. I imagine due to the fact that some transactions don't exist at that specific (month day day_name hour).

My question is how do i get all 24h irrelevant if they have records or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['month', 'day', 'day_name', 'hour'])['amount']
         .sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .stack()
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope not to be wrong, but you can try this:

```
df2 = df.resample('1H').sum().copy()
```

This will resample your dataset for every hour from 0 to 23 and will sum the values. It will also create the nan for missing timestamps.
Late but hope it helps.